# How to recover this garbled text?

Tags: text, encoding, character-encoding

I want to recover text that was partly made unreadable due to foreign characters:

`Esse e-mail \u00E9 gerado automaticamente para informa\u00E7\u00E3o ao cliente e n\u00E3o deve ser respondido.`

It's in Portuguese. Do you know a simple way to make messages like these readable? I think I need some decoder / encoder.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are javascript utf-16 character constants.  This page will "make them readable":  http://www.rishida.net/tools/conversion/

Without knowing more about the form of these messages (are they in seperate files?) it's hard to offer more advice.

Comment: Perfect! I didn't need programmatic conversion. This was all I needed. Thank you for the prompt reply.